# What kind of technology need I use if the function doWork will run a long time

Tags: android

The function doWork maybe run 20s, I think the system will cause ANR problem.
I don't know what kind of technology I need use to prevent ANR, AyncTask, local server, thread, IntentService or others.
Could you give me some sample codes? Thanks!

AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
     doWork(context,intent);         
  } 

  private void doWork(Context context, Intent intent){      
     //It will running a long time.
  } 

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enable_disable_boradcast_receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

</manifest>
```

EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.R;

public class EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnExit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }           
        }); 

    }

   public void enableBroadcastReceiver(View view){
       ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
       PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

       pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
               PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   public void disableBroadcastReceiver(View view){
       ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
       PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

       pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
               PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled broadcst receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }     

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/enable_broadcast_receiver"
        android:onClick="enableBroadcastReceiver"
        tools:context=".EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver" />
   <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
       android:text="@string/disable_broadcast_receiver"
       android:onClick="disableBroadcastReceiver"
       tools:context=".EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit" 
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: AsycTask should be fine. Dare I ask what you could possible have to do that will take 20 seconds every time text message is received? Seems a bit shady to me.

Comment: Thanks! This is only sample.

Comment: "sample" or not, still seems shady to me.

Comment: Will another message arrive during those 20 seconds? If so, a second AsyncTask will block until the first one finishes, and you are back to a /de-facto/ single-threaded app. (Unless if you start the AsyncTask with .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR). And in THAT case, you may run your device out of CPU time, with too many threads!)

Comment: Thanks! When a sms arrived, I will check if it is marked as black list in remote cloud server database, and the sms will be forward to one or several numbers if this sms has passed check,
So I think it will be spend many time, and it maybe cause ANR problem.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use IntentService ? If so, which one is better between AsycTask and IntentService? Could you give me some sample code?